# php DOMElement appendChild unwanted nesting

Tags: php, domdocument, nested, appendchild

I want a list of xml node in a given xml node. The code sample below should do it? (but doesn't)

```
$doc= new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$rootel = $doc->createElement("drobj");

$el1 = $doc->createElement("el1");
$rootel->appendChild($el1);

$el2 = $doc->createElement("el2");
$rootel->appendChild($el2);

$doc->appendChild($rootel);

$doc->saveXML();
```

Result is

```
<drobj>
  <el1>
    <el2></el2>
  </el1>
</drobj>
```

I expected

```
<drobj>
  <el1></el1>
  <el2></el2>      
</drobj>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc= new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$rootel = $doc->createElement("drobj");

$el1 = $doc->createElement("el1");
$rootel->appendChild($el1);

$el2 = $doc->createElement("el2");
$rootel->appendChild($el2);

$doc->appendChild($rootel);

$doc->save("test.xml");
```

This works perfectly fine. I tested it out.

The only thing i changed was the last line to save the xml to a file.